# How to export an instance of a library created inside a custom hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, locomotive-scroll

I am using LocomotiveScroll in a React application and I have created a custom hook called `useLocoScroll` to handle the initialization and destruction of the LocomotiveScroll instance in order to make LocomotiveScroll work with gsap's ScrollTrigger. The hook works fine and I can use it to enable smooth scrolling and also use the ScrollTrigger in my app.

However, I now need to access the LocomotiveScroll instance from outside the hook so that I can call its methods directly. Specifically, I want to be able to call the scrollTo method of the instance to scroll to specific positions in the page, and I also want to be able to force a scroll to the top of the page whenever React Router changes routes.

I have created a function that does exactly that but it uses a new instance of the Locomotive scroll, while this worked fine if the custom hook is set to `false` and the first instance of the LocomotiveScroll does not exist. When the custom hook is set to `true` it no longer works. I am just assuming that that's because I am creating 2 instances of LocomotiveScroll.

```
  useLocoScroll(true);
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
    scrollRef.current = scroll;

    if (scrollRef.current) {
      scrollRef.current.scrollTo('top', {
        offset: 0,
        duration: 600,
        easing: [0.25, 0.0, 0.35, 1.0],
        disableLerp: true,
      });
    }
  }, [pathname]);
```

I have tried adding the function to the LocomotiveScroll instance inside the hook and returning it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the custom hook:

```
import { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import ScrollTrigger from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

const useLocoScroll = (start) => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!start) return;

    const scrollEl = document.querySelector('.App');

    let locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: scrollEl,
      smoothMobile: false,
      smooth: true,
      multiplier: 1,
    });

    locoScroll.on('scroll', ScrollTrigger.update);

    ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy(scrollEl, {
      scrollTop(value) {
        if (locoScroll) {
          return arguments.length
            ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
            : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.y;
        }
        return null;
      },
      scrollLeft(value) {
        if (locoScroll) {
          return arguments.length
            ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
            : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.x;
        }
        return null;
      },
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        return {
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
        };
      },

      pinType: document.querySelector('.App').style.transform
        ? 'transform'
        : 'fixed',
    });

    const locoScrollUpdate = () => {
      if (locoScroll) {
        locoScroll.update();
      }
    };

    new ResizeObserver(() => {
      if (locoScroll) {
        locoScroll.update();
      }
    }).observe(document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'));

    ScrollTrigger.addEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
    ScrollTrigger.refresh();

    return () => {
      if (locoScroll) {
        ScrollTrigger.removeEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
        locoScroll.destroy();
        locoScroll = null;
      }
    };
  }, [start]);
};

export default useLocoScroll;
```

This is what I've tried

```
// ...rest of the code
    const scrollToTop = () => {
      if (locoScroll) {
        locoScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);
      }
    };

    ScrollTrigger.addEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
    ScrollTrigger.refresh();

    return () => {
      if (locoScroll) {
        ScrollTrigger.removeEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
        locoScroll.destroy();
        locoScroll = null;
      }
    };
  }, [start]);
  return scrollToTop;
};

export default useLocoScroll;
```

The error I receive is saying that scrollToTop is not defined.

How can I modify this hook to allow me to access and use the LocomotiveScroll instance outside the hook?

Answer (score 1):

`scrollToTop` is inside your `useLayoutEffect`, and the outer layer cannot be obtained. You can use `useRef` to cache this method, and then use it externally, but it will only be mounted on the ref after `useLayoutEffect` is executed. like:

```js
const ref = useRef(null);

// ...rest of the code
ref.current.scrollToTop = () => {
  if (locoScroll) {
    locoScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);
  }
};

ScrollTrigger.addEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
ScrollTrigger.refresh();

return () => {
  if (locoScroll) {
    ScrollTrigger.removeEventListener('refresh', locoScrollUpdate);
    locoScroll.destroy();
    locoScroll = null;
    ref.current = null;
  }
};
}, [start]);
return ref.current;
};

export default useLocoScroll;
```

Comment: I did try this but I still get an error saying `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'scrollToTop')`

Comment: It appears that I've resolved the issue by caching the locoScroll instead of the function, and referencing it externally like so `const scrollRef = useLocoScroll(true);`. While this solution seems to be effective within the App.jsx file, it's possible that there could be complications if I were to use it in a separate file, as it may result in a new instance of the locoScroll being initiated.

Comment: If you want a `singleton mode`, you should cache this instance at the outermost layer, use the mounted instance for the first time, and then reuse the previous instance. In addition, the `scrollToTop` method call should be inside `useEffect`, so as to ensure that the scrollToTop method can be retrieved every time. I don't know if it will solve your problem